# Why can't I boot into Windows boot manager from GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-8

I just recently, recently being last night, installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop for school. I really want to learn about Ubuntu and how to use it. The main problem I am having is trying to start into Windows from GRUB. Whenever I restart my laptop, I am taken to GRUB and try to select the Windows boot manager, but it gives me and error and goes back to the GRUB menu. I tried using Boot-Repair, but that just made more options pop-up in GRUB. Does anyone know what is happening, and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error?  Is this a UEFI machine? Is secure boot on or off?  Some UEFI machines with secure boot on just will not boot Windows from grub (bug 1091464)

Comment: @ubfan1 Well, when I turned off SecureBoot there error stopped popping up. However, when I choose to boot into Windows it just goes straight back to the grub menu.